# Radiobuttons and checkboxes alignment issues for IE9

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, browser, user-controls, webbrowser-control

I had been developing on a server that uses IE8.

When I deployed my application to another server using IE9, all my web controls become unaligned as below.

Checkbox:

[image]

and

RadiobuttonList:

[image]

What is the best way to make the controls aligned again? I also have the same problem in Chrome.

EDIT: I'm creating my controls dynamically in code-behind.

```
                    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                    TableCell td1 = new TableCell();
                    td1.Attributes.Add("colspan", "2");

                    CheckBox chkInclude = new CheckBox();
                    chkInclude.Text = "Include";
                    chkInclude.Checked = true;
                    chkInclude.AutoPostBack = true;

                    td1.CssClass = "border";

//--------CSS---------
.border 
{
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: This is hard to debug without seeing the html, but it seems like the labels elements are being overriden by some css class in your page.

Comment: I've added some codes for the checkbox

Comment: I dont think label elements are being overridden? If i specify the CSS, do they overwrite the CSS in site.css?